# Race condition with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, race-condition

I am trying to write some code that unbolds every item in an HTML `select` box and then bolds the player's name. It only works if I have an alert box in between lines, like so:

```
$("#users > option").css("font-weight", "normal");
alert('AHAHSDYHSAUDHSAUDHSAUDH');           
$('#users option[value="' + strPlayer + '"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
```

If I remove the alert box the player item doesn't become bolded. My only guess is that JQuery operations are asynchronous.. Not sure how to solve this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the select box being filled asynchronously?

Comment: can you post the relevant HTML, or a fiddle?

Comment: `css()` is definitely not asynchronous. Can you create a short [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: jQuery DOM manipulations, `.css`, etc. aren't asynchronous.

Comment: They are synchronous (avoid double negative :D)

Comment: @Esailija: It's not a double-negative, it's a negative and a negative adjective :)

Comment: Worksforme: http://jsfiddle.net/Abpdw/ - altough the bold is not displayed in Opera

Comment: @minitech, I think Esailija's referring to the negative `a` prefix in `asynchronous`. Esailija, you're right, but I usually prefer to repeat the terms used in the question, to make sure the questioner and I are on the same page :)

Comment: @PaulPhillips: `<select id="users" size="20" multiple="multiple">` and I am filling the contents with JQuery's append function.

Comment: Yes, but where is that data coming from? Do you have it when the page first loads, or after you make a request to the server? If you don't have it on first load, what could be happening is that you're querying the `select` before the AJAX response has finished.

Comment: @PaulPhillips: When I receive a WebSockets message I handle it with Javascript and append items sometimes.

Comment: Try filling the box with a static (i.e. unchanging) list of data, don't append to it, and see if your bolding works then.

Comment: I can think of a really terrible fix that might work, but I'm not posting it because I don't understand why there's a problem in the first place.

Comment: The race condition is not between the two css calls.. it is caused by some other part of your code that might be overwriting the options, or resetting their styling..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use CSS for the first part (setting all to non-bold), and jQuery for the last part (setting the user's name to bold). It's better to apply default, predictable styles using CSS rules, and then customize using jQuery:

```
<style type="text/css">
#users > option {font-weight:normal;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#users option[value="' + strPlayer + '"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
</script>
```

---

**Edit:**

If the overlap of the two statements is conflicting, try removing the overlap:

```
$('#users option:not([value="' + strPlayer + '"])').css("font-weight", "normal");
$('#users option[value="' + strPlayer + '"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Comment: Thanks but the reason I need this is because in between rounds different player names become bold (depending on who the current leader is)